# Is there a way to align rotated object to grid by marking some faces and somehow tell Blender they should be parallel to grid?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms, snapping

That`s the whole question basically

Comment: this is what the local orientation is supposed to do, but maybe show some screenshots of what you want and of a precise situation?

Comment: yes, that`s it, thanks!!!